# decimal to p number system conversion for fractions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, discrete-mathematics, logic

Let's look *decimal* to $p$ number system conversion for fractions.

Given $T_{10}$ $(0<T_{10}<1)$ which has $m$ decimal digits (is represented by $10^{(-m)}$). Number of digits of $T_p$ is $n$.

And now question.In my book is written that to have $10^{-m}$ in $p$ number system $p^{-n}\leq$ $10^{-m}$
and $n\geq$ $\frac{m}{\lg p}$.

Can you explain me why $p^{-n}\leq$ $10^{-m}$ ?.

Comment: You cannot write $10^{-m}$ for positive integer $m$ exactly in a base-$p$ system unless $p$ is a multiple of $10.$ What exactly did your book say about what it means "to have $10^{-m}$ in $p$ number system"? It may help if you edit your question to use the exact same words the book used in the exact same way, because the wording of the question right now is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a way to understand the relationship if ‘m’ could go infinite, so I’m going to assume your book means ‘m’ is finite.  Since logs of negatives are imaginary, I will also consider only positive values of p in my answer.

There are going to be many cases where no exact conversion of fractional values is possible from base 10 to arbitrary base p.  In those impossible cases, ‘n’ goes unboundedly large during the conversion process.   When ‘n’ is unboundedly large, the value of $p^{-n}$ shrinks to zero.

Therefore, the inequality stated in your book is trivially true in any inexact conversion case.  A finite value of $10^{-m}$ will always be larger than something unboundedly shrinking to zero.

In the cases where an exact and conversion of an m digit decimal fraction to an n digit, base ‘p’, fraction is possible, the decimal fraction being converted can always be written as a fraction of one integer dived by another integer.  The integers in the denominators must not be relatively prime for the conversion to be finite and exact.

Therefore, Only a very few choices for ‘p’ will allow ‘n’ be finite.

The part of the question you are asking about defines a 1 in the least significant position of a decimal fraction AKA ${10^{-m}}$ and compares that to a value, base p.

Notice that the value in base 10, when written as a ratio, is $ 1 \over ( 2^m 5^m )$.  There are prime factors of 2 and 5 in the denominator.

Therefore ‘p’ must also have factors of 2 and 5 iff n is to stay finite.

Base ‘p’ is either the trivial case p=10 (making the relationship equal), or p must be a multiple of 10.

Lets examine  the smallest ‘p’ where this is possible, p=20.
Converting the value 10^{-n} into base p=20 would have the pattern:

$ {1 \over 10}, { 1 \over 10^2 }, {1 \over 10^3}, {1 \over 10^4}, { 1 \over 10^5 }  →   {2 \over 20^1}, { 4 \over 20^2 }, { 8 \over 20^3 }, { 16 \over 20^4 }, ( {1 \over 20^4} + {12 \over 20^5} ) $

In the first four conversions,  n=m.

However, you can see that $20^{-m}$ computes a smaller value than $10^{-m}$. Your textbook's inequality appears wrong or perhaps taken out of context.

But:
In the fifth  conversion, m=5, there is a carry out from the n=5 to n=4 digits in the base p representation,  This is because the value of m=5, base 10, converts to a value larger than p whenever I try to put all of the value in the n=5 digit.  The attempted conversion has a digit value of 32 which is greater than p=20, by 12.  Therefore, I was  forced to do a carry out, and leave the valid modulo p value of 12 at place n=5.

Multiple digit conversion is the key to understanding the point of your book's inequality.

In my example, m=5, n=4, p=20 I gave the exact conversion:
$10^{-5} =  (1) 20^{-4} + (12) p^{-5}$

Typically, during exact conversion ... the value of $10^{-m}$ will become a *sum* of nonzero digits, base p, after the conversion.  BUT -- *All* the converted digits are required to correctly add up to the value of the original base 10 fraction.

The inequality you ask about is restricting our attention to a single digit of the conversion, base p.  But, since the inequality removes all digits of the conversion except one digit ...  we are left with only part of the required sum.

This is the reason that $p^{-n}$ will usually be less than $10^{-m}$. Removing any of the converted digits results in a sum that is less than $10^{-m}$.

During conversion, you will rarely see a single digit in one representation convert to a single digit in a different representation and base.  I think that's why your author may have overlooked the cases where the inequality doesn't appear to hold.